# Can you remove measurements - g/kg/ml etc from a Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, data-cleaning

I am doing some pre processing for a data set on one particular column 'Title' I have already removed numbers and punctuation. But also want to remove measurements as well. The measurements are not in a separate column, they're in the title column.

```
            #Load data set
df = pd.read_csv (r'example')
#df = pd.read_csv (r'example)


# remove numbers and punctuation 
df['Title'] = df['Title'].str.replace(r'[^\w\s]+', '')
df['Title'] = df['Title'].str.replace('\d+', '')
print (df['Title'])
```

[Return and the dataset column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkXvD.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['Title'] = df['Title'].str.replace(r'\sg$|\skg$|\sml$', '')
```

as an example.
or more generally removing the last word will amount to:

```
df['Title'] = df['Title'].str.replace(r'\s[a-z]+$', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex again.

```
df['Title'] = df['Title'].str.replace('xg$|g$|kg$|ml$', '')
```

The dollar sign acts as an anchor for the end of the string.